# Scanstate error 71 while running on win 10 unit with user having elevated access

Tags: migration, usmt

While the  USMT is running, a step where scanstate with arguments are run we  face error 71

```
SCANSTATE.EXE Version 10.0.14393
25-02-2019 | 12:57:22 | Migration STDOUT : (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
25-02-2019 | 12:57:22 | Migration STDOUT : Unable to start. Check the log parameter and/or process permissions.
25-02-2019 | 12:57:22 | Migration STDOUT : ScanState return code: 71
25-02-2019 | 12:57:23 | Migration INFO   : Migration code return value: 71
25-02-2019 | 12:57:23 | Migration INFO   : Checking USMT results
```

User  is already having elevated access, what could be the issue?

Does the user need to be local admin?

Answer (score 0):

#### What could be the issue?

Look at the `ScanState` log.

> Return Code 71
>
> USMT_INIT_OPERATING_ENVIRONMENT_FAILED
>
> A Windows Win32 API error occurred
>
> Data transfer has begun, and there was an error during the creation of
> migration store or during the apply phase. Review the ScanState log or
> LoadState log for details.

Source [Return Codes (Windows 10) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-return-codes)

Comment: there is no log files created,, it just  does not run,, any suggestions ?